# How to create fully controlled dropdown in semantic-ui-react

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I want to create a fully controlled dropdown in order to use [react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window) to show really long list of items in it.

I've checked docs, and there is no any example of controlled dropdown with `Dropdown.Item` specified.

This is how my component looks like:

```
<Dropdown
  placeholder="Filter Posts"
  clearable={true}
  search={true}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  text={tagOptions[1].value}
  value={tagOptions[1].value}
  onSearchChange={this.handleChange}
>
  <Dropdown.Menu>
    {tagOptions.map(option => (
      <Dropdown.Item key={option.value} {...option} onClick={this.handleItemClick} />
    ))}
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>;
```

I've encounter with 2 issues:

1. Initial value is not appears, I dig into the code, and saw that if i don't pass `options` property it won't find the given value, therefore, it will not be shown. I can use the `text` property, but it seems like a hack.
2. I need to implement `handleItemClick` by myself, and I see that there is logic in the [original handleItemClick](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/src/modules/Dropdown/Dropdown.js#L675-L710).

Any suggestions? did I missed something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've able to hack it around with using ref on the dropdown and passing the original `handleItemClick` method.

The only downside for now is that keyboard nav is not works :\

Seem like it was not designed to be fully controlled.

https://codesandbox.io/s/ql3q086l5q

Answer (score 3):

The dropdown module simply doesn't have support for controlling it's inner components, that being said this is the closest I've gotten to a controlled dropdown with react-window support. I'm posting it here for anyone in the future that wants a select dropdown with virtualisation without a headache.

### VirtualisedDropdown.js

```
import React, { forwardRef, useCallback, useRef, useState } from "react"
import { Dropdown, Ref } from "semantic-ui-react"
import { FixedSizeList } from "react-window"
import "./VirtualisedDropdown.scss"

const SUI_DROPDOWN_MENU_HEIGHT = 300
const SUI_DROPDOWN_MENU_ITEM_HEIGHT = 37

const VirtualisedDropdown = ({
  options, value,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  const dropdownRef = useRef()
  const listRef = useRef()

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

  const OuterDiv = useCallback(({ style, ...props }, ref) => {
    const { position, overflow, ...restStyle } = style
    return (
      <Ref innerRef={ref}>
        <Dropdown.Menu open={open} {...props} style={restStyle}>
          {props.children}
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Ref>
    )
  }, [open])

  const InnerDiv = useCallback(props => {
    return (
      <Dropdown.Menu className="inner" open={open} style={{ ...props.style, maxHeight: props.style.height }}>
        {props.children}
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    )
  }, [open])

  return (
    <Dropdown
      className="virtualised selection"
      onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
      onOpen={() => {
        setOpen(true)
        listRef.current.scrollToItem(options.findIndex(i => i.value === value))
      }}
      // This causes "Warning: Failed prop type: Prop `children` in `Dropdown` conflicts with props: `options`. They cannot be defined together, choose one or the other."
      // but is necessary for some logic to work e.g. the selected item text.
      options={options}
      ref={dropdownRef}
      selectOnNavigation={false}
      value={value}
      {...restProps}
    >
      <FixedSizeList
        height={options.length * SUI_DROPDOWN_MENU_ITEM_HEIGHT < SUI_DROPDOWN_MENU_HEIGHT ? options.length * SUI_DROPDOWN_MENU_ITEM_HEIGHT + 1 : SUI_DROPDOWN_MENU_HEIGHT}
        innerElementType={InnerDiv}
        itemCount={options.length}
        itemData={{
          options,
          handleClick: (_e, x) => dropdownRef.current.handleItemClick(_e, x),
          selectedIndex: options.findIndex(i => i.value === value),
        }}
        itemSize={SUI_DROPDOWN_MENU_ITEM_HEIGHT}
        outerElementType={forwardRef(OuterDiv)}
        ref={listRef}
      >
        {Row}
      </FixedSizeList>
    </Dropdown>
  )
}

const Row = ({ index, style, data }) => {
  const { options, handleClick, selectedIndex } = data
  const item = options[index]

  return (
    <Dropdown.Item
      active={index === selectedIndex}
      className="ellipsis"
      key={item.value}
      onClick={handleClick}
      selected={index === selectedIndex}
      style={style}
      title={item.text}
      {...item}
    />
  )
}

export default VirtualisedDropdown
```

### VirtualisedDropdown.scss

```
.ui.dropdown.virtualised .menu {
  &.inner {
    margin: 0 -1px !important;
    left: 0;
    overflow: initial;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    border: 0;
  }

  > .item {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To solve first problem remove `clearable={true}` and `text={tagOptions[1].value}`
2. What `handleItemClick` function should do?

Comment: Cansole log tagOptions[1]. to check did you get there any value. 
{console.log('tagOptions[1].value', tagOptions[1].value)}

Comment: Yes,
You can play with this sandBox https://codesandbox.io/s/ql3q086l5q